# Change FocusRing color of NSTextField, NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

How to change focusRing color from Blue to Red.

(This question is in continuation with [Generic validation on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494661/generic-validation-on-input), here instead of setting a default blue focus, I need red one.)

The default looks like this :

[image]

I need something like this (*Note: The image shown is not perfect as drawn inside Box*) :

[image]

I tried few things from

1. http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/241956-how-to-change-focus-ring-color.html
2. [Cocoa focus ring color animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049405/cocoa-focus-ring-color-animation)
3. http://toomasvahter.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/drawing-focus-rings-in-nscell-and-nsview/

but no success.

Your help is needed.

Comment: Focus ring color is set by the user.

Answer (score 1):

sub class NSTextview and insert below code

```
-(void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent{

    CALayer *lay = [self layer];
    CGColorRef  myColor=CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0, 0, 1, 1);
    [lay setBorderColor:myColor];
    [lay setBorderWidth:4];
    //[self setWantsLayer:YES];
    [self setLayer:lay];
    [self makeBackingLayer];
    //CGColorRelease(myColor);
}   

-(void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent{

    CALayer *lay = [self layer];
    CGColorRef  myColor=CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0, 0, 1, 1);
    [lay setBorderColor:myColor];
    [lay setBorderWidth:0];
    //[self setWantsLayer:YES];
    [self setLayer:lay];
    [self makeBackingLayer];
    //CGColorRelease(myColor);
}



-(void)updateTrackingAreas{
    [super updateTrackingAreas];
    if (trackingArea){
        [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
        [trackingArea release];
     }

    NSTrackingAreaOptions options = NSTrackingInVisibleRect | NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveInKeyWindow;
    trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:NSZeroRect options:options owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];

}
```